# How to copy a database to sap hana from postgresql with talend?

Tags: postgresql, talend, hana

well my problem is, how could I copy a database with Talend from PostgreSQL to SAP HANA without needing to write a job for every table ?

The reason for this is, because it could take some long time to prepare all those jobs, while taking in consideration, having at least 200 tables, which at least have 30 columns.

I tried tTransferDatabase plugin, but I can't succeed to transfer it to SAP HANA, it gives me an error that it can't copy schema (while it successfully worked copying it to other database in PostgreSQL), and I am sure that the schemas names are right.

here is the error:

> Exception in component tTransferDatabase_1
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at org.apache.ddlutils.PlatformFactory.createNewPlatformInstance(PlatformFactory.java:86)
> at org.apache.ddlutils.PlatformFactory.createNewPlatformInstance(PlatformFactory.java:124)
> at com.devjpcb.transferdatabase.TransferDatabase.getPlatformDestine(TransferDatabase.java:179)
> at com.devjpcb.transferdatabase.TransferDatabase.copySchemaToDatabase(TransferDatabase.java:249)
> at local_project.aaasa_0_1.aaasa.tTransferDatabase_1Process(aaasa.java:836)
> at local_project.aaasa_0_1.aaasa.runJobInTOS(aaasa.java:1130)
> at local_project.aaasa_0_1.aaasa.main(aaasa.java:951)

Is there maybe a chance to do something like .. for each table in connection, table guess schema, copy columns from table to other side of tmap, run ?

Any advice would be helpful ;), Thank you !

Comment: if you're on enterprise then you can use Dynamic types, which means you only define 1 "record" in the schema, and talend maps everyting into that record dynamically. https://help.talend.com/display/TalendStudioforCloudDeveloperGuideSummer1EN/3.6+Using+dynamic+schema

Answer (score 0):

With some work, you could use the example job created by [rbaldwin on Talend Exchange](https://exchange.talend.com/#marketplaceproductoverview:gallery=marketplace%252F1&pi=marketplace%252F1%252Fproducts%252F247%252Fitems%252F350); note that it starts with files, not a database. But you could easily create a job that loops through all your database tables and does an extract to file, to then use as the starting point.

Another option is [Bekwam's](http://bekwam.blogspot.com/2011/06/dynamic-schemas-in-talend-open-studio.html) solution

Comment: Thank you for your time,